# Angular : DatePicker not required but still invalid

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am trying to do a form in Angular with a datePicker that's not required

```
<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="ruleForm.invalid"
            (click)="addRule()">
            <span>ADD</span>
</button>
<form *ngIf="ruleForm" name="ruleForm" [formGroup]="ruleForm" class="w-100-p" fxLayout="column">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" fxFlex="9">
                        <mat-label>End Date</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" name="endDate" formControlName="endDate">
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

But my field is still invalid when not giving a value : [No value at first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMiTA.png)

The only way to go around that is to give it a value then erase it :[Value erased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23RlS.png)

How to do it?

Edit:
The problem with in the initialization of the form :

```
return this._formBuilder.group({
        endDate: [moment(this.rule.endDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY')],
    });
```

I don't know why but replacing it by

```
return this._formBuilder.group({
        endDate: [this.rule.endDate? moment(this.rule.startDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY'): ''],
    });
```

resolved my problem

Comment: Share form initializing code

Comment: maybe you have provided Validators.required rule for End Date in your .ts File. Remove that and it will work.

Comment: can you please provide a working demo on stackblitz ?